# Elastic horizontal image scroll locking into place with corresponding thumbnails on mobile website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to work on a mobile portfolio site and the goal is to have horizontally scrolling images and a thumbnail menu corresponding to the images.

I find facebook's implementation of their "People you may know" section very close to what i'm trying to achieve. Where a full swipe will lock on to a particular div image element, and a slight swipe will elastically return back to the current image or go to the adjacent image depending on how far the swipe was done.

[image]

I currently have the following wireframe:
[image]

Part of the restriction, however, is that I do not wish to use jquery.
I have a list where it's able to scroll due to the following markup:

**horizontal_image**

```
<div id="horizontal_image">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/imgA.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/imgB.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/imgC.jpg"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Thumbnails**

```
<div id="thumb_nail">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/smallimgA.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/smallimgB.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="../img/smallimgC.jpg"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Stripped down CSS**

```
white-space: nowrap;
width: 900px;
overflow-x: auto;
```

The problem I'm struggling with most is how to get the elastic swipe feature working where a slight swipe would return the div to the original locked position, but a swipe that maximizes a reveal of a previous or next image would lock the latter image into place. All without jquery.

Thank you for taking the time to read through this.